# Bootstrap datepicker sends nothing to ng-model

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a simple to-do app that has a three part form for a to-do title, description of the task, and a bootstrap datepicker that picks a due date, the form looks like;

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <p><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="Title" ng-model="formData.title"></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="Description" ng-model="formData.description"></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg datepicker"  placeholder="Due Date" ng-model="formData.duedate"></p>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createTodo()">Add</button>
</form>
```

Further down the HTML is the JS for the datepicker, and it renders fine.

```
<script>
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      startDate: '+3d'
    });
</script>
```

When I select a due date for the task, it populates the field with that date. Submit then sends the form data for the fields that aren't drawn with my Bootstrap datepicker (i.e are just text input) but formData.duedate is undefined. Can I not bind this to an Angular model? Is it stripping out everything that is a custom field type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend explained this.

Selecting the date from the date picker doesn't update the actual Angular model that underlies this, it's just updating the contents of the text box. Amending the function that draws the datepicker to;

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '+3d',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      console.log(dateText, inst);
      $scope.formData.duedate = new Date(inst.currentYear, inst.currentMonth, inst.currentDay);
    }
  });
```

Updates the model when you click on it (which you need to do to select a date), which passes it through nicely.